# Rendering Unreal Engine 4 sequence: character timeline animations don't show, and behave as if they are in play mode

Tags: animation, rendering, unreal-4, skeletal-animation, video

I have a cinematic sequence with camera cuts set up that can be previewed properly. These scenes involve human skeletal character animations that I made frame by frame in the timeline. Everything works fine in the timeline preview, but when I start to render out the cinematic, the human characters function as if they are in "play" mode, namely dropping down to the ground directly, without playing out the animations that I made. Why is this? How could I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sequence timeline, make sure the `SkeletalMeshComponent0` exists besides the `ControlRig`.

Click on the characters. In the Details panel, uncheck the "Enable Gravity" option.

Then it's fixed!